# Node.js module problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, real-time

I have a question want to ask you guys .... Recently i found out Node.js plus Socket.io can make a good real time web . But what i scare is what happened if one day Socket.io gone ? Like if the Author unpublished the module or what ever happened that module is gone so all the project depending on that module is down too ? Please answer me i know maybe this is stupid question for some of your guys ... but that what i scare about and i don't know if it gonna happened or before have any module is gone somehow then Project of people depending on it is suck after that anything like that happened before ?? . I just want to know what i gonna do if it happened .. and will it happened ? Thanks

Comment: Modules are installed, it doesn't matter what the author does, other than of course new updates won't be available, unless someone else writes them. This is nothing to worry about!

Comment: Source code is available.  Clone it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All node modules are installed locally on your machine/server. You use the `npm` tool to do that automatically for you. See https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm.html

Even if a module gets deleted from the registry and nowhere to be found on the internet, it is still on your project unless you delete it yourself.

Comment: Yahh you're right ... maybe i'm worry too much ... thanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

The worst thing that could happen is that there wouldn't be more updates/support/bug fixes for that specific module. But aside from that, the module is installed in your own project so what was working for you will still work.

Comment: Ya thanks ... you're right .. some time I'm just being stupid xD . Coz i'm Working on a big project ... so i'm just being silly ... anyway thanks ... have a good night